# RoR is calling a method in a loop when the collection is empy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I have a .each loop in a view that keeps trying to iterate over an empty collection. When it attempts to go through the loop, it throws an error when it tries to call a method on an object that doesn't exist. I even tried putting the loop inside an if statement testing the collection for its size/emptiness and it still gave the same error.

The code thats causing `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Code without an ID):`

```
<% @game_board.cards.each do |card| %>
    <%= image_tag card.image %>
<% end %>
```

Controller action:

```
def show
  @game_board = GameBoard.find(params[:id])
  @card = @game_board.cards.new
end
```

This same code is actually in another view but is working fine, both views given the same @game_board object. The console even shows that the collection is empty. The reason its showing record not found is that image is really an instance method of Card that is getting the image from a Code object but the issue is that image is getting called in the first place.

I also showed the size of the collection in the view and it showed 1 but when I tried showing the ID of the first or last of the collection, nothing rendered.

Comment: please add both views and both controllers and the exact error

Comment: I just added the controller action as well as some additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the new card I was creating in the show action. It was being added to the collection so I changed it to `@card = Card.new`.

Answer (score 1):

**Conditional**

For this type of problem, you could also use a conditional statement to see if the `collection` is populated:

```
#app/views/controllers/your_view.html.erb
<% if @game_boards.present? %>
   <% @game_boards.each do |game| %>
       ...
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Yes, it adds a level of complexity, but if you don't know if your `@instance variable` will be populated, it will allow you to focus on creating an exception-free experience for the user :)